# My flex container items are not displaying in default direction (row)

Tags: css, flexbox

`I am trying to create YouTube UI clone I made navbar, then I made a container in which one div is for menu with class name "menu" and second div is for videos with class name "main", and I gave display flex to the container, the width of menu div is 15% and for videos width is auto or 85% (I tried both) and the problem is that the second div(videos) is not displaying along with menu div on the row direction.`

[screenshot of clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Uyg.png),[screenshot of HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89mon.png),[CSS code for container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsHDe.png),[CSS code for menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU8Gg.png),[CSS code for main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAPGP.png).

`the menu div and main div for videos should be in one row but I tried and I think there is something wrong in the code but what's that mistake I am not getting.`

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(179, 172, 172);
    width: 15%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hello you can create a snippet of you code to make the reproduction of your code easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing flex-wrap

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```